# Sorting from multiple loops

Tags: python, sorting

I have 7 different loops grabbing information from different places in the same format but as they're coming from different areas the data is muddled up.

```
for event in soup.find('dual').find_all('event'):
 print event

for event in soup.find('int').find_all('event'):
 print event
```

I want to sort all the information returned from these loops by a specific column number (i.e column seven places along). They are currently in CSV format and I have tried writing them to a CSV file and sorting them from that. Is there a way of sorting from these different loops without having to write to any files.

Comment: What does your data look like? What kind of information are you working with? Have you tried looking at the inbuilt `sorted()` function that python has?

Answer (score 0):

```
master_list = []

for event in soup.find('dual').find_all('event'):
    master_list.append(event)

for event in soup.find('int').find_all('event'):
    master_list.append(event)

for event in soup.find('whatever').find_all('event'):
    master_list.append(event)

print sorted(event)
```

You may have to write your own comparison function so that `sorted` knows how to sort the list.